# Using Angular2 datatable directives

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am using Angular2 datatable in a project to display tables with paginations.

Here is the link to the library https://github.com/mariuszfoltak/angular2-datatable.

Can somebody please clear some doubts I have with regards to the `#mf="mfDataTable"`? The developer has used in his demo and using the `mf.data` to refer to the data.But when I use that mf., my table does not get populated but when I use it without that .mf,my data is loaded in the tables.

So, do I need that `#mf="mfDataTable"` or what am I missing?

Below is my code.

cheers!!

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" [mfData]="products" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="5">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <mfDefaultSorter by="gtin">GTIN</mfDefaultSorter>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <mfDefaultSorter by="fdoname_en">Name Eng</mfDefaultSorter>
                        </th>
                        <th class="no-sort hidden-sm-down">
                            <mfDefaultSorter by="fdoname_fa">Name Per</mfDefaultSorter>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let product of products | SearchPipe : searchText">
                        <td><a [routerLink]="['/app/master/products',product.gtin]">{{product.gtin}}</a></td>
                        <td>{{product.fdoname_en}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.fdoname_fa}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/app/master/productEdit', product.gtin]">
                                Edit
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr *ngIf="!products.length">
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td colspan="6">No Records Found</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr *ngIf="(products | SearchPipe : searchText).length === 0">
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td colspan="6">No matches</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="12">
                            <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5, 10, 25]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting data because you are directly looping over [products]. Change [products] to [mf.data] then the data will fetch using datatable component.

Then you will be able to get all advantages like sorting and pagination.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" [mfData]="products" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="5">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <mfDefaultSorter by="gtin">GTIN</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th>
                <mfDefaultSorter by="fdoname_en">Name Eng</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th class="no-sort hidden-sm-down">
                <mfDefaultSorter by="fdoname_fa">Name Per</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let product of mf.data | SearchPipe : searchText">  /* change products to mf.data */
            <td><a [routerLink]="['/app/master/products',product.gtin]">{{product.gtin}}</a></td>
            <td>{{product.fdoname_en}}</td>
            <td>{{product.fdoname_fa}}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/app/master/productEdit', product.gtin]">
                    Edit
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="!mf.data.length">  /* change products to mf.data */
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="6">No Records Found</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="(mf.data | SearchPipe : searchText).length === 0"> /* change products to mf.data */
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="6">No matches</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12">
                <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5, 10, 25]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```